# Can anyone explain this probability statement?

Tags: probability

It's really confusing to me. I would appreciate if someone can explain is in less confusing manner.

Let's say we flip three coins, and we want to know the probability of getting 2 or more heads. In order to do this, we'd need to add the probability of getting exactly 2 heads with the probability of getting exactly 3 heads. The probability that any single coin will be heads is .5 (the probability that the coin will be tails is the same, .5).

The probability of 3 heads is easy to calculate -- this can only happen in one situation, where all three coins are heads, or .5 * .5 * .5, which equals .125.

The probability of 2 heads is a little trickier -- there are three different combinations that the three coins can configure themselves in to end up with 2 heads. We show this in the table below, using H for heads, and T for tails.

```
Coin 1    Coin 2    Coin 3
H         H         T
T         H         H
H         T         H
```

Each one of these has a probability of .5 * .5 * .5, so we just multiply 3 * .125 to get .375, the probability that we'll get 2 heads.

We then just have to add up the probability of getting 2 heads to the probability of getting 3 heads to get .5, the probability of getting 2 or more heads when we flip 3 coins.

Q) Each one of these has a probability of .5*.5*.5? How can it be explained.

Q) My goal is to find Let's say we flip three coins, and I want to know the probability of getting 2 or more heads.

Comment: By symmetry, the probability of $2$ or more heads is equal to the probability of $2$ or more tails and these are mutually distinct events with no other possibilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We simply need to add up the probability of all the possible scenarios:

\begin{align}P(2 \text{ or more heads}) &= P(HHH)+P(HHT)+P(HTH)+P(THH)\\
&=\frac 12\cdot \frac12\cdot \frac12+\frac12\cdot \frac12\cdot\frac12+\frac 12\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12+\frac12\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12\\
&=\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18\\
&=\frac48\\
&=\frac12\end{align}

The reason that every case is equal to $\frac12\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12$  is down to the fact that there are only $2$ options on each throw. If you considered rolling $3$ dice and wanted to get a value greater than $5$ on $2$ or more throws, each probability we add together would be different as there is a $\frac13$ chance of throwing $5$ or more and a $\frac23$ chance of throwing less than $5$

Comment: Thank you :) How can the probability be 1/3 for throwing 5 or more. isn't suppose to be 1/6??

Comment: @user456 You have 6 options (1,2,3,4,5,6) and throwing 5 or more means throwing a 5 or a 6 which is 2 of a possible 6, or 1/3

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible results for every coin to come out, so you obtain $2^3=8$ possible outcomes. Each outcome has probability $1/8=0.125$; this should answer your first question.

Now, if you are looking for the probability of obtaining heads at least twice, there are four possibilities for this to happen just as you explained in your question. Thus the probability is $4/8=1/2=4*0.125$; this should answer your second question.

Comment: So, if i want to find probability that 1 coin out of 3 is heads. How can I do it?

Comment: If you mean precisely one coin is heads, then you best compute that this is 1-(P(at least two are heads)+P(none is heads)). The first one we just found to be $1/2$, the second event only occurs when all three coins show tail and thus has probability $1/8$. Thus the probability of having heads precisely once is $0.375=3/8$.

Comment: If you mean at least one coin displays heads, then it is 1-P(none shows heads) and this occurs only if all three show tail and thus the probability is $1-1/8=7/8$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.:)  Sorry I can't upvote yet not enough reputations.

Comment: `1-(P(at least two are heads)+P(none is heads))` How is the first one `at least two are heads`1/2?

Comment: That was your original question which I explained in my answer.